# Getting PXE-E53 "No boot filename received" Windows Deployment Services

Tags: wds

I have configured WDS on a Servre 2012 box. It isnt the DC and it doesn't run DHCP, I have a 2008r2 box that does. I have configured WDS, installed one machine with it, and it worked fine. I have the exact same laptop, Dell E5530, and it returns PXE-E53 "No boot filename received". All of the setting are the same in the BIOS, the are both plugged into a switch on the same subnet. I even configured Option 66 in DHCP. I really dont know wht the issue could be, it is awfully odd.

Comment: Do you have enough available up addresses in your DHCP scope?

Comment: @joeqwerty yes I do